# create new TikZ key with code and style tags

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Assume I want to perform a complicated calculation within a TikZ key defintion. What is the recommended way to do this?

Reading through the manual and digging around in other questions led me to believe that the solution might look somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mykey/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{mykey/.code={%
      % perform complicated calculation involving #1, #2 and #3 here
      \def\x{5}
    },
    scale=\x
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mykey={1,2,3}]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \x
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: `\x` should probably be global..

Comment: define another key with `/.store in` handler and use that in the code or use `\pgfkeysgetvalueof` and define the value as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do this :

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  mykey/.code args={#1,#2,#3}{
    % perform complicated calculation involving #1, #2 and #3 here
    % for example
    \pgfmathparse{(#2-#1)*#3}
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/scale=\pgfmathresult}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, mykey={1,2,3}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw[->, thick, red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]